# Distinction between Treatment and Control Group

Tags: difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, control-group

I am struggling to understand how to interpret the treatment and control group in the following case of DID regression. We need to estimate the causal effect of brick kilns on downwind PM2.5 monitor readings. Using the wind direction we identified the number of brick kilns that are upwind to monitor on a given day. Also brick production is a seasonal activity and operates only for 5 months in a year. We run the following equation:

PM2.5 = β0 + β1 Kilnsd + β2 Seasond+ β3 Kilnsd × Seasond + θXd + ed

where Kilnsd= no of kilns upwind to monitor identified on a particular day

season= dummy variable for kilns off and on

Xd = vector of meteorological controls

Kilnsd × Seasond= interaction term  between the number of upwind kilns and the brick season
The author of the paper states that we measure whether changes in pollution between the brick-producing season (approximately November to March) and the nonproducing season (the rest of the year) were larger on days when the air pollution monitor was downwind from more kilns as compared to days when the air pollution monitor was downwind from fewer kilns after controlling for other factors.

In this case, instead of binary treatment variable, we have continuous values. I am not able to distinguish between what is treatment group and what is controlled?

Comment: Isn't the definition of a control group when the treatment variable is zero?

Comment: There isn't always a "control" versus a  "treatment" **group** in an observational study like this. As another comment says, it's more important to think about what the "treatment" consists of. Here, it seems to be when upwind kilns are on (treatment) versus off (control). So it's more of a treatment time period rather than a treatment group. Then there's the magnitude of the treatment, the number of such active kilns.

Comment: Wouldn't the authors trying to say that there are comparing days when kilns are few versus kilns are more in number as treatment and control group in DID set up?